# How to Sort Data In Next js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I've an ecommerce website and I want to sort Data By Categories , I try to do it with apis but it kill my server , and now i try to do it with redux , that means store the data in the store and filtred from that store but it doesn't work , If any one has an idea how to do that tell me

Container.js

```
import {useState } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import Product from '../Product';

export default function Container({products}){

    
    const router = useRouter();
    const [a,setA] = useState(0);
    const [b,setB] = useState(6);
    
    const {category} = router.query;
   
    
    const sidebar = () => {
        const sidebar = document.querySelector('.collectionsidebar')
        sidebar.classList.remove('-left-full')
        sidebar.classList.add('left-0')
    }

    const previous = () => {
        if( a  >= 6){
            setA(a-=6);
            setB(b-=6);
        }
    }
    const next = () => {
        if( b < products[0].length)
            {
                setA(a+=6);
                setB(b+=6);
            }
    }

    return(
        <section className = " w-full lg:w-3/4 pb-40 lg:pb-22 p-5 space-y-5 h-screen scrollbar">

            {/* Filter Part */}

            <section className = "relative flex items-center justify-between p-5 bg-gray-50 shadow">
                <section className = "lg:hidden">
                    <i onClick = {sidebar} className='bx bx-filter cursor-pointer text-2xl' />
                </section>

                <section className = "flex items-center space-x-3 relative">
                    <select className = "text-xs outline-none p-2 cursor-pointer from-current rounded-full border px-4" 
                            onChange = {e => router.push(`/collections?category=${category ||"all"}&sort=${e.target.value}`)}>
                                <option value="featured">مميزة</option>
                                <option value="price-low-to-hight">السعر , من الرخيص الى الاغلى</option>
                                <option value="price-hight-to-low">السعر , من الاغلى الى الرخيص</option>
                                <option value="alphabetically-A-Z">أبجديا , ا الى ي</option>
                                <option value="alphabetically-Z-A">أبجديا , ي الى ا</option>
                    </select>
                    <span className="hidden lg:inline-flex text-xs lg:text-sm text-gray-700">صنف حسب </span>

                </section>
                
                <p className = "hidden lg:inline text-xs text-gray-700">
                    <span className = "hover:text-black cursor-pointer" onClick = {() => router.push('/')}> الصفحة الرئيسية </span> / المنتجات
                </p>
                
                
            </section>

            {/* Product Feed */}

            <section className = "feed grid md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-10 p-1 border-b">
                {
                    products[0].slice(a,b).map(({id_produit,image,Nom,prix,rating,Description,titre,promo})=> (
                        <Product id = {id_produit} image={image} category={titre} promo={promo} title={Nom} price={prix} description={Description} rating={rating} />
                    ))
                }
            </section>

            {/* Pagination */}

            <section className = "justify-center mx-auto flex items-center space-x-5">
                 {
                     a >= 6 ?   <i onClick={previous}
                     className='bx bx-left-arrow-alt text-lg  rounded-full p-2 text-gray-100 bg-primary  active:text-gray-100 cursor-pointer' />
                     :
                     <i
                     className='bx bx-left-arrow-alt text-lg  rounded-full p-2 text-gray-400 cursor-not-allowed bg-gray-200 active:bg-sidebar active:text-gray-100' />
                 }  
                {
                    b < products[0].length ? <i onClick={next}
                    className='bx bx-right-arrow-alt text-lg  rounded-full p-2 text-gray-100 bg-primary active:text-gray-100 cursor-pointer' />
                    : <i
                    className='bx bx-right-arrow-alt text-lg  rounded-full p-2 text-gray-400 cursor-not-allowed bg-gray-100  active:bg-sidebar active:text-gray-100' />
                }
              
            </section>

        </section>

    )
};
```

SideBar.js

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

export default function Collection_SideBar({categories}){

    const router = useRouter();

    return(
        <aside className = "w-1/4 text-right border rounded shadow  mt-5 mb-44 scrollbar pb-5 space-y-5 hidden lg:inline  ">

            {/* Category */}

            <section className = "space-y-4">
                <h3 className = " w-full bg-gray-50 shadow border-gray-900 text-xl font-semibold p-2 font-serif">التصنيفات</h3>

                <div className = "space-y-4 px-5">
                    {categories.map(cat => (
                        <h5 onClick = {() => router.push(`/collections?category=${cat.titre}`)} key={cat.id_cat} className = " border-b border-gray-100 pb-2 cursor-pointer text-sm hover:text-black text-gray-600 hover:border-gray-300 transform duration-300">{cat.titre}</h5>
                    ))}
                </div>

            </section>

        </aside>
    )
}
```

Comment: There is nothing in the snippets you attached that show any filtering/sorting that you intend on to do on the `products[0]` array. The only thing here are the query string params that you are passing on routes to specify a value for category (to filter) and a value for sort (for the data to be sorted by).
Passing these values alone wouldn't magically sort and filter your products array.
You need to have some logic on the component like this to filter: `product[0].filter(a=> a.Category === category)` and like this to sort  `product[0].sort((a,b)=> a.SomeProp -  b.SomeProp)`

Comment: Thank You I fixed that probleme with filter() function , i just create a state  in the index page called category , setCategory , and give it to the child component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution , I just create a state that called category (in index page) and give the sidebar component the setCategory

index page

````
export default function Products({products,productsLimit}) {

  const items = useSelector(selectItems);
  const [categories , setCategories] = useState([]);
  const [category , setCategory] = useState([]);

  useEffect(async () => await axios.get("/api/products/categories").then(res => setCategories(res.data)),[]);

  console.log(category)

  const filtredProducts = products[0].filter(val => {
                            if (category.length === 0) {
                                return val
                            } else if (
                                val.titre
                                .toString()
                                .toLowerCase()
                                .includes(category.toString().toLowerCase())
                            ) {
                                return val;
                            }
                        });

    return (
        <div className="font-poppins bg-white overflow-hidden h-screen">
            <Head>
                <title>تسوق الآن</title>
                <link rel="icon" href="https://icons-for-free.com/iconfiles/png/512/online+shop+shopping+icon-1320191096068276528.png" />
                <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
                <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fruktur&family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
                <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"/>
                <link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"/>
                <meta name="description" content="اشتري مستلزماتك الالكترونية الان بارخص الاثمنة عند كوداتا , الدفع عند الاستلام و كدلك الدفع عبر الحساب البنكي" />
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
                <meta name="keywords" content="accessoires electronique , مستلزمات الالكترونية , pc portable , حاسوب  " />
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
            </Head>

            <Header products={products}/>

            <SideBar />

            <SearchBar products={products} />

            <Basket items={items} />

            <ResponsiveSideBar categories = {categories} setCategory = {setCategory} />

            

            <main className = "container mx-auto flex">

                <Container products={filtredProducts} productsLimit = {productsLimit} />

                <Collection_SideBar categories = {categories} setCategory = {setCategory} />

                
                
            </main>

        </div>
    )
}```
SideBar.js
```import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

export default function Collection_SideBar({categories,setCategory}){

    const router = useRouter();

    return(
        <aside className = "w-1/4 text-right border rounded shadow  mt-5 mb-44 scrollbar pb-5 space-y-5 hidden lg:inline  ">

            {/* Category */}

            <section className = "space-y-4">
                <h3 className = " w-full bg-gray-50 shadow border-gray-900 text-xl font-semibold p-2 font-serif">التصنيفات</h3>

                <div className = "space-y-4 px-5">
                    <h5 onClick = {e => setCategory([])} className = " border-b border-gray-100 pb-2 cursor-pointer text-sm hover:text-black text-gray-600 hover:border-gray-300 transform duration-300">الكل</h5>
                    {categories.map(cat => (
                        <>
                            <h5 onClick = {e => setCategory(cat.titre)} key={cat.id_cat} className = " border-b border-gray-100 pb-2 cursor-pointer text-sm hover:text-black text-gray-600 hover:border-gray-300 transform duration-300">{cat.titre}</h5>
                        
                        </>
                    ))}
                </div>

            </section>

        </aside>
    )
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

you can use sort-by package provided by npm :[sort-by npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sort-by)

example :

- npm install sort-by

  ```
   import SortBy from 'sort-by'
   const products = [{id: 7,name: 'P1'}, {id: 3,name: 'P2'}, {id: 4,name: 'P3'}];
   products.sort(sortBy('name','id'));
  ```

Comment: sort-by was last updated in 2017 and contains some serious vulnerabilities that are unlikely to be fixed. There are open PRs from over a year ago now that have not been merged. You should avoid this package!